# Как выполнить откат базы данных только с файлами MDF и LDF, но без файла резервной копии?

Tags: sql-server

Я использую MSSQL Server 2017. Я хочу откатить базу данных до времени сегодняшнего утра. Возможно ли это только с файлами MDF, LDF?

Answer (score 1):

Коротко - штатными средствами нет.

Если модель восстановления базы Full, то в журнале должны сохранится записи всех транзакций, сделанных с момента последней резервной копии. Теоретически, эти транзакции можно откатить, но штатных средств для этого нет. Может помочь сторонний софт, типа ApexSQL Log ($1,999).

Если есть последняя резервная копия и журнал (Full Recovery model), то можно штатными средствами восстановить БД из копии и накатить из журнала все изменения до любой точки. А без резервной копии - увы!

Comment: это означает, что без резервной копии я ничего не могу сделать?

Comment: Да. Без резервной копии у Вас есть только актуальное состояние. Что-то можно делать с сочетанием резервной копии и журанала, но без резервной копии журнал по сути бесполезен. Теоретически из него конечно можно попытаться что-то выудить, но только что-то конкретное. Если определённая строка менялась вчера и сегодня, и обе эти транзакции лежат в журнале, то по идее это вчерашнее значение можно выудить. Но задача эта нетривиальная.

Comment: понял спасибо  !

Comment: Простите, возможно я Вас обманул! В журнале должна быть информация о старых значениях. Посмотрите приложение ApexSQL Log. У них вроде есть триальная версия.

Answer (score 0):

Если журнал транзакций (файл LDF) ведётся с самого начала существования БД, то теоретически есть некоторая вероятность выполнить откат, но скорее всего без резервной копии у Вас ничего получится.